# Making cells independent of each other in a Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter

I would like to have a few independent computations, all them in their own cells in a jupyter notebook -- each cell having its own "main" function if you will.  Currently it looks like the union of all cells containing Python 
code is essentially one big Python program.

In brief I am asking a Jupyter version of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47479/how-to-make-cells-independent-with-each-other-in-notebook) question for Mathematica.

Comment: Each cell already can be run independently. I'm not sure what you mean

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Variables defined in cells become variables in the global namespace.
To isolate variables to a local scope, put them in functions:

```
In [1]: 

    def foo():
        x = 1
        return x
    foo()

In [2]: 

    def bar():
        x = 2
        return x
    bar()
```

Comment: OK, but one function cannot span over multiple cells.

Answer (score 12):

You can execute a Jupyter Notebook cell in a pseudo-local namespace using [`jupyter_spaces`](https://github.com/davidesarra/jupyter_spaces) magics.

For example, let's define a variable in a "normal" cell.

```py
x = 10
```

Assuming Jupyter Spaces is available in the environment (`pip install jupyter-spaces`), we can load the `jupyter_spaces` magics.

```py
%load_ext jupyter_spaces
```

Finally, we can execute a cell in a specific namespace, which has access to the `globals` variables.

```py
%%space name_of_the_space
y = 2 * x
```

In this example, `y` won't be available in the global namespace just as if we had executed the cell in a local namespace.

The documentation on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/jupyter-spaces/) or [GitHub](https://github.com/davidesarra/jupyter_spaces) includes additional examples.